# Error Missing $ inserted

Tags: errors

```
\textbf{54.Consider the operations \\
f(X,Y,Z)=X$'$YZ+XY$'$+Y$'$Z$'$ and g(X,Y,Z)=X$'$YZ+X$'$YZ$'$ + XY }\\
Which one of the following is correct?\\
(A) Both \{f\} and \{g\} are functionally complete\\
(B) Only\{f\} is functionally complete \\
(C) Only \{g\} is functionally complete \\
(D) Neither \{f\} nor \{g\} is functionally complete\\
\vspace{2mm}\\
\textbf{55.$\sum\limits\_${x=1}^{99}$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ =..........}\\
\vspace{4mm}\\
\end{document}
```

Error! `Missing $ inserted`.

Help me out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\textbf{55.$\sum\limits\_${x=1}^{99}$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ =..........}` should not have the internal `$` signs around `{x = 1}^{99}`, that's definitely gonna cause a problem. But, well, um, there are some much more fundamental problems than that, in that this is really not how to make good use of LaTeX and I think there are some more basic misunderstandings here, but that's a bit beyond our scope. You should have a look at a starter guide to help you get going

Comment: See this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Comment: Can you correct the code for me...so that it runs without any error and I get the desired O/P.

Comment: Um, well, if you replace the third line from the bottom with `\textbf{55.$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{99}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ =..........}`\\ it *will* run, but, but it will not be very good LaTeX

Comment: I got it.....But why will it not be good Latex?

Comment: this will not be good latex for several reasons. some of these reasons are: there is not a clean distinction between text and math; the structure is not clear (an enumerated list is hard coded); lines are broken explicitly rather than instructing latex to break lines according to the actual structure; ... really, it would be good for you to refer to a good introduction to become familiar with the basics.